# Hide search bar after few time in android

Tags: android, search, android-edittext

I'm creating a search bar that will search the content of listview .I have done some code and now its working fine but one thing more i want to add is that when user doesn't touch screen for some time then this searchBar should automatically hide.Is it possible in Android or not if possible,please give me some advice about this.
**Thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement an onTouchListener

```
 // Catch touch events here
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        System.out.println("Touch Down X:" + event.getX() + " Y:" + event.getY());//hide search bar
    } 
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        System.out.println("Touch Up X:" + event.getX() + " Y:" + event.getY());//shows the search bar
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Then in this you'll want to reference the button and set it's visibility:

```
  searchbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); or View.INVISIBLE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of onUserInteraction api of android Activity.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserInteraction

You may need to turn on/off a flag onUserInteraction. A thread may then keep polling to read this flag for say every 30s or so. And if the idle time is greater than your desired time, you can then hide the searchbar.